# JAXB Annotated class skip fields on Runtime

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I have a Java class which contains 15 fields that need to be transformed into xml. The standard JAXB work well, and if we want to skip a field then that field can be marked as `@XmlTransient`.

However in my situation Users are able to filter the fields that need to be transformed into xml. so I am looking for a solution where fields can be marked `@XmlTransient` at runtime.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="cpu_specs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CpuSpecs {


    private String spec1;
    private String spec2;
    private String spec3;
    ...
    private String spec15;

}
```

I have an object of `CpuSpecs` ready to be transformed into `xml`. I have a list of fields that need to be skipped as `List<String> toSkip`.

**Note:** Please I would prefer a solution without `MOXY`.

Comment: Here is how your use case can be handled with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html